# Browser cache issue in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JavaScript code:

```
  $('#selectionoptions').change(function() {
  var courseId = $(this).val();
  $.get('../php/lecturer_getcourse_info.php',
      { course_id: $(this).val() },
      function(courseData) {
          var description = courseData.description;
          $("#coursecontent").html(description);
          ...
```

Assume I can also modify 'description' and save it back to the db. Now, on Firefox every time I refresh the page I see the correct description; but on IE I have to clear the cache before I see the correct description....

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to read [the second fact in this article](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason being in IE you have to false the Ajax Calls not to cache.

Use this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

or use a completely different ajax call rather than $.get such as:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(data){
    alert('data returned!');
  },
  cache: false
});
```

Comment: I would not want to re-write my website, where should I put .ajaxSetup so that all my gets in all webpages are not cached?

Comment: Put it in a file that is loaded on all of you pages, and make sure its loaded prior to any of the Ajax calls happening. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I had no idea and this issue has been bugging me for some time!